# How to call a Matlab function from a callback function inside a GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a GUI in Matlab, which is a function itself, and includes a couple of push buttons. By pressing on the push button, I am supposed to call other functions. For instance, one of the callback functions should call a function that performs a segmentation of a video into frames. The video and the function for frames segmentation lies in the same folder as the GUI function. Yet, when calling the function from the callback function does not produce anything, not even errors.

An example of the code I have in a callback function:

```
function extractFrames_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
x= imread('wait.png');
axes(handles.displayArea);
imshow(x);
pause(0.1)
%call frame extraction function here
frameExtraction()
I = imread('done.png');
axes(handles.displayArea);
imshow(I);
set(handles.results,'String','Frame has been extracted ');
```

All commands execute, except the call to the function frameExtraction().

Comment: Set a breakpoint there and check what happens when you *Step in* at this line.

Comment: It looks correct! If all the other lines in the your callback function runs correctly, the error must be in your `frameExtraction`-function!

Comment: Jens is right, the code seems alright.
There should be no problem with locating the function and image files too. In a case where any file is not found, Matlab would return an error like `Undefined function or variable 'frameExtraction'.`

when you said "all commands execute, except the call to the function frameExtraction()", would that mean both images `x` and `I` are displayed on axes `handles.displayArea` too? if it does, that shows your code is running fine too.

Comment: * continuation *
Try looking into `frameExtraction()`, what should be the expected outcome. if the frames are supposed to `imwrite`-en/created into a specific folder, could the path you have given is incorrect?